# Multiple ViewModel : Pass event to other ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a `Button` in `ShellView` I want this Button fired to `FooViewModel` but not work, Any idea.

```
<Window x:Class="CM.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action FooViewModel.About]"/>
</Window>


namespace CM.ViewModels
 {
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IShellViewModel
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {
        }
   }

   public class FooViewModel
   {
         public void About()
         {
             MessageBox.Show("About method fired");
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: i think that viewmodel present data and command for a view. But in this case you want to fire a command for a button in another view. Don't you think it break perception of mvvm :?

Answer (score 1):

Caliburn.Micro has the [Event Aggregator](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator) for passing messages between view models.

In this scenario you could add a method to `ShellViewModel` that the button invokes. This publishes a message on the event aggregator that `FooViewModel` can listen for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Mediator pattern, as described in the articles written by Marlon Grech and Josh Smith:

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/a-mediator-prototype-for-wpf-apps/

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/mediator-v2-for-mvvm-wpf-and-silverlight-applications/

Comment: Ah, sorry, I don't use that one myself. I'd probably take a look at the "Event Aggregator" in the Caliburn.Micro documentation at codeplex.com.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution works fine, but perhaps not the right approach. If it is not the right approach guidance masters.

```
    //Register with Windsor
    public class ViewInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Component.For<IShellViewModel>().ImplementedBy<ShellViewModel>().LifestyleSingleton());
            container.Register(Component.For<IFooViewModel >().ImplementedBy<FooViewModel>().LifestyleSingleton());
        }
    }

<Window x:Class="CM.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action About]" cal:Action.Target="CM.ViewModels.FooViewModel"/>
</Window>

namespace CM.ViewModels
 {
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IShellViewModel
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {
        }
   }

   public class FooViewModel : IFooViewModel
   {
         public void About()
         {
             MessageBox.Show("About method fired");
         }
   }
}
```